# Ubuntu 18.04 mouse on Lenovo Thinkpad X240 not working after suspend/hibernate

Tags: mouse, suspend, touchpad, thinkpad

Lenovo Thinkpad X240, Ubuntu 18.04. After suspend/hibernate the touchpad is not working. Keyboard or external mouse works. I'm new to Ubuntu

log:

```
11:03:24 wpa_supplicant: dbus: Failed to construct signal
11:03:23 kernel: rmi4_physical rmi4-00: rmi_driver_set_irq_bits: Failed to     change enabled interrupts!
11:03:23 kernel: rmi4_f03 rmi4-00.fn03: rmi_f03_pt_write: Failed to write to F03 TX register (-6).
11:03:23 kernel: rmi4_f01 rmi4-00.fn01: Resume failed with code -6.
11:03:23 kernel: rmi4_physical rmi4-00: rmi_driver_reset_handler: Failed to read current IRQ mask.
11:03:23 kernel: rmi4_smbus 0-002c: failed to get SMBus version number!
11:00:59 spice-vdagent: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
11:00:58 pulseaudio: [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio agent with ofono: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provided by any .service files
11:00:43 kernel: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
11:00:42 wpa_supplicant: dbus: Failed to construct signal
11:00:40 systemd-rfkill: Failed to open device rfkill0: No such device
11:00:40 kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_PR.CPU0._PDC, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old issue, but it is still relevant today.

I have the same problem Lenovo Thinkpad X240, Ubuntu 20.04

My solution:-

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system-sleep/rmi-driver
```

Add the following:-

```
#!/bin/sh

case $1 in
  post)
    rmmod rmi_core
    rmmod rmi_smbus
    modprobe rmi_core
    modprobe rmi_smbus
    ;;
esac
```

Set executable:-

```
sudo chmod +x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/rmi-driver
```

On wake-up the touchpad will be working :)