# Ubuntu 18.10 problems with suspending and resuming

Tags: keyboard, mouse, suspend, 18.10, mousepad

I have a X240 with ubuntu 18.10 installed. When I suspend the lapop by closing the lid, the mouse will sometimes become unresponsive when I resume. Other times, just the 2-finger-scrolling stops working and other times the keyboard will stop working as well.

I found this other post, which seems to be some of the same problems, but with no replies: 
[ubuntu 18.04 mouse/thinkpad lenovo x240 not working after suspend/hybernate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097080/ubuntu-18-04-mouse-thinkpad-lenovo-x240-not-working-after-suspend-hybernate)

Do any of you have this problem and/or solutions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with 18.10 and this fixed my problem (worked with my latest laptop a lenovo x220), I reinstalled xserver-xorg-input-all

[Keyboard and mouse unresponsive after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483416/keyboard-and-mouse-unresponsive-after-suspend)

Hope this helps.

This issue is ongoing, comes and goes with updates since version Ubuntu 10, latest update causing this yet again was 9/2/2019.